# URL Parameter in view_email_url in marketing cloud emails

Tags: marketing-cloud

is there any way to add url parameter into VAWP link ? and differentiate which VAWP link is clicked in the ampscript.
we want to create 2 different VAWP links in the email with different contents. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any control over the VAMP as it's a default generated version of your email. You can link to it using: `%%view_email_url%%`.

Now, if you want to create two VAMPs, you'll need to use CloudPages. Create two CloudPages, and link to them from your email. Every page will have it's own URL, so it would be clear on the reports on which page a customer have clicked. Or you can add an alias to each link to make it easier:

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(YOUR_LP1_ID))=%%" alias="VAMP_1">View as webpage</a>
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(YOUR_LP2_ID))=%%" alias="VAMP_2">View as webpage</a>
```

`CloudPagesURL` function links to your LandingPage and the URL link that is generated is appended with an encrypted query string that contains system personalization strings referencing to the email. You can use these strings to pull in values from your Data Model and to create any kind of personalization you had in your email..

You'll be saying: But why the `RedirectTo` function? It helps avoid broken links due to appended tracking parameters that are added automatically.

**Reference:**

- [CloudPagesURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm)
- [System personalization strings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5)